# Set footnote numbering to additive asterisks

Tags: footnotes

I want to make a few footnotes that aren't counted in numbers, but in asterisks - like this:

```
Text*, more text**, more text***.

*   Footnote1
**  Footnote2
*** Footnote3
```

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, notitlepage, twoside, twocolumn, openany]{book}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
    Test1\footnotemark[*], 
    Test2\footnotemark[**] und
    Test3\footnotemark[***]

    \footnotetext[*]{test1}
    \footnotetext[**]{test2}
    \footnotetext[***]{test3}

\end{document}
```

I'm almost there, but the footnote asterisks are not where I want them to be, as you can see:
[image: Minimal Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produces errors because the optional argument of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` must be a number, which `*`, `**` and `***` are not. When a LaTeX run has errors, interpreting the output isn't very useful. The priority must be to fix the errors before looking at the DVI or PDF output.

Here is one way to achieve what you want, using `\prg_replicate:nn` from `expl3`. The `\relax` isn't necessary unless some other place has sloppy code, but it doesn't hurt.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=6.5cm]{geometry} % for the screenshot
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\prg_replicate:nn{\value{footnote}}{\relax*}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test1\footnote{test1}
Test2\footnote{test}
Test3\footnote{test3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\the` and `\relax`?

Comment: @egreg I think `\the` is indeed not necessary. I hadn't checked the doc and thought it expected an integer denotation, but in fact an integer expression is enough. I've removed it. The `\relax` is for the unlikely case where `\thefootnote` would be expanded after a command with a star form... Is it a sin? :-)

Comment: @egreg (also, the star form of `\relax` is quite powerful :)

Comment: To be clear, the `\relax` prevents mistakenly triggering the use of a star form in cases like: `\edef\x{\thefootnote}\expandafter\foowithstarform\x`, `\edef\x{\noexpand\foowithstarform\thefootnote}\x` or `\expandafter\foowithstarform\expanded{\thefootnote}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out later, that I oversimplified my minimal example, because I hade a `\twocolumn` command in my original document, which did not work with the original answer.
But I did figure it out - so here my solution for `\twocolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=6.5cm]{geometry} % for the screenshot
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\prg_replicate:nn{\value{footnote}}{\relax*}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \twocolumn[{%
        Test1\footnotemark,
        Test2\footnotemark,
        Test3\footnotemark
    }]
    \footnotetext[1]{Hi1}
    \footnotetext[2]{Hi2}
    \footnotetext[3]{Hi3}

%   continue with regular footnotes
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
    Test\footnote{test1}
    Test\footnote{test2}
    Test\footnote{test3}

\end{document}
```

[image: twocolumn solution]